# How to deal with string containing spaces in Vim script?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, microsoft-windows, string-manipulation

I have the following command in my vimrc:

```
execute "set path+=".getcwd()."/**"
```

It works well if current working directory is like `/home/tamlok/my_work/`. However, if the directory contains spaces, such as `D:\Program Files\vim\`, vim will complain.

I suppose that I can fix this using `substitute()` function to replace all the spaces with escaped spaces. What would an experienced vimmer do here?

Another issue is the `\` in Windows. If `getcwd()` gets `D:\Program Files\vim\`, do I need to escape the `\` with `\\` or replace it with `/`?

For now I handle it like this:

```
let mycwd=substitute(getcwd(), '\\', '/', 'g')
let mycwd=substitute(mycwd, ' ', '\\ ', 'g')
execute "set path+=".mycwd."/**"
```

Is that OK? Any help is appreciated! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `fnameescape()`.  It will escape all special characters in a given string containing a path to a file to match the standard of the current operating system.

For more on this see `:help fnameescape()`

Comment: Thanks very much! Is `/` the same as `\\` in the file path in GVim on Windows?

Comment: True, but beware of the difference between `fnameescape()` and `shellescape()`.  The former is used when passing arguments on Vim's command line, so that they are not molested by Vim.  The later is used when passing arguments to external commands, so that they are not molested by the shell.  On Windows there's also `shellslash`, which will have a major influence on the number of hairs on your head if you ever need to mess with `!command` and friends.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try just to use `/` in paths, and escape whitespace like this `\` .
For example I add this line in my vimrc:

```
set rtp=C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Vim/vim74/vim.exe
```

Than if you will command `:echo &rtp` you can see:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim74/vim.exe
```

Note that here is no `\` before whitespace.

Comment: Thanks very much! However, I got the path from a function call. So I think I can't control the separator in the path. An escaping function is needed here, just as what the selected answer suggests.

Comment: @tamlok, I am sorry, but I don't use functions yet - you are deeper vimer then I :-) Share your knowledge, when you will find the answer, please)

Comment: Hi, EvergreenTree's answer is just the key to the question! :) Thanks!

Comment: @tamlok, I am confused by search results by words "evergreentree" in Google. Perhaps, I didn't understood you right.

Comment: Hi, EvergreenTree is a user in StackExchange and posted an answer in this question. Just see above. :)