Print if a file is a "New file"
While starting to edit a file, I want to print a message stating if the file is new.
To be clear, when I write vim file, I want the message "New File" to be printed, if I am not just editing the file, but also creating it.
I wrote the following code using the function system(). Please note that, if a symlink points to a non-existing file, by editing the symlink the real file will be created. That is why I use realpath to determine if the file exists or not.
function! IsFileNew()
  let filename = expand('%:p')
  if !empty(filename)
    let filename = system('realpath ' .. shellescape(filename))
    " https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-deal-with-string-containing-spaces-in-vim-script
    let filename = system('stat ' .. fnameescape(filename))
    if v:shell_error != 0
      echo 'New file'
    endif
  endif
endfunction

augroup PrintFileNew
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * call IsFileNew()
augroup END

Is there a way to achieve the same result without using the function system()?

What is wrong with the default behaviour? Vim already tells you when it is editing a new file using the [New] flag

Nothing is wrong. I have removed the flags, as I want a clean look and just want this information about new file.

How did you remove this flag? As far as I know, you cannot disable this and Vim will always show this

Check this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140898/vim-hide-status-line-in-the-bottom and set shortmess+=F

I have this in my vimrc: set noshowcmd noshowmode shortmess=atIF.

Well, this certainly belongs into your question. I would say don't do this if you want the output of the New being shown then.

Just listening for BufNewFile should be enough.

I tried that one. It did not work as expected.

I tried that one. It did not work as expected. If you try my solution above, and the flowing code autocmd BufNewFile * :echo "New file". The latter does not print anything, while the former does.

It works very well -- as expected... (no template plugin would work without that). If you don't see anything, it's quite likely you load/activate other things when starting vim. Things that clear the messages already printed. If you replace echo with echom, you'll see with :messages that "New File" has been printed. Unless it's related to your unusual setting of 'shortmess'.

PS: to answer your exact question you're looking for filereadable() and resolve()... but... there is no need for such a convoluted approach. Beside, every time you'll go back to a buffer with no file associated, you'll have a message when listening to BufEnter. Changing windows will be enough to observe that.

After following the @Luc advice in the comments above, it seems the next solution works for me. So he has the credits.
I do agree that using the autocmd BufNewFile * :echo "New file" would be enough if I add :set shortmess-=F. But since I want a more clean look, I want to keep the F.
function! IsFileNew()
  let filename = expand('%:p')
  if !empty(filename)
    let filename = filereadable(resolve(filename))
    if filename == 0
      echo 'New file'
    endif
  endif
endfunction

augroup PrintFileNew
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter * :call IsFileNew()
augroup END



With this solution if you open a window (like with :help help for instance), and go back to the file-less window, you should observe the message again and again.
Out of curiosity, is :echom (instead of :echo) also filtered by your shortmess setting?

Yes it is. The thing is with the F in the shortmess. Also if I use :messages as you suggested it prints this Messages maintainer: The Vim Project. In my solution above, I now have changed from BufEnter to BufWinEnter, which seems to reduce the verbosity. The :help help issue is fixed with if !empty(filename).
